# HTML5 Canvas: Colorize image

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas, colorize

I would like to change the color of the image/canvas. My existing code:

```
var loader = new PxLoader()
var image = loader.addImage('images/balloon.png')
loader.addCompletionListener(functio() {
  var canvas = $("<canvas>").attr("width", "200").attr("height", "200");
  var context = canvas[0].getContext('2d');
  context.clearRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
  context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
  // colorize??????
});
```

How can I colorize it - further manipulation of the context (I would like to use Pixastic.process if possible)?

Comment: Did you look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688961/how-do-i-tint-an-image-with-html5-canvas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If by *colorize* you mean change the background colour, then use....

```
context.fillColor = '#f0f';

context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.attr('width'), canvas.attr('height'));
```

If you mean to *tint* the colour, try...

```
var data = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.attr('width'), canvas.attr('height'));

for (var i = 0, length = data.data.length; i < length; i += 4) {
    data.data[i] = Math.max(255, data.data[i]);
}

context.putImageData(data, 0, 0);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ceu7t/).

That will max the red value for each pixel. Experiment with it to get the effect you desire.

Comment: No... I would like to "tint" the image so it would have more red color for example.

Comment: @xpepermint Get the image data (`getImageData()`) and increase the *red* value for each pixel.

Comment: @xpepermint I am doing an example and will update the post when it's ready.

Comment: @alex BTW, I didn't get this `Math.max(255, data.data[i])`. I guess it will always return 255 so why to use this function? Why not `data.data[i] = 255` simply?

Answer (score -1):

explained in this question:

[How do i tint an image with HTML5 Canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688961/how-do-i-tint-an-image-with-html5-canvas)

and in here: http://www.playmycode.com/blog/2011/06/realtime-image-tinting-on-html5-canvas/