# Colorize Background-Image

Tags: html, css

I need to colorize a post-it image (like this one [here](http://www.rodsbot.com/images_maps_cache/3363-map-assoc.jpg) ) depending on a rgb-Value.

My problem is the following: The outer parts of the image need to be transparent as the image is placed in front of different background-colors.

Second, I need the currently yellow color of the image changing to the given rgb-value. (not animated)

I first thought about making the yellow part of the image transparent, too and put a colorized element beyond it. But this would colorize the outer parts as well which should stick to the documents background-color.

Any ideas on that?

Thanks in advance,
Woyzeck

Comment: How will the image be colored?  Is it going to be done dynamically (such as through a form with color sliders)?  Or will it be done statically (PageA will have a blue image, PageB will have a green image, etc.)?

Comment: there are many post-its on the page. each of them gets a color-rgb-value from the server. Is it what you were asking?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by tinting the image drawn in a `<canvas>` element. (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688961/how-do-i-tint-an-image-with-html5-canvas) for an example) and then generating a data URI you can use to show the image.

Not sure this can be done with pure CSS, but I'd love to be proven wrong :)

Comment: Well, I guess you could always have four of those images (white, red, green and blue) and then overlap them (with smart z-indexes - white at the bottom) while playing with the RGB post-its' opacity value to create custom colors... I guess that would work (and would be 100% CSS!). But your answer is simpler. :-)

Comment: @mbinette Good point! That would probably work too. It might not be too messy if you handle some of it with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your fast suggestions!

I'm sure they would work as well. But I came across another good solution that works for me [here](http://webdesignandsuch.com/posts/css3-post-it/index.html).

Completely CSS, but of course it doesn't use an image as I was trying before.