# How do I make an <image> inside of SVG change color?

Tags: html, css, svg

I made an SVG in Photoshop. The two items between the  tags below were layers I had in the PS file before I exported it to SVG (which, I think, is why they are  instead of . Now, I'm trying to make one of those  item turn (#00599c) blue upon mouseover.

I imagine CSS is the easiest way to accomplish this but I can not figure out how to do it.

Thanks

```
   <style>
      .hover { 
        background-color: #00599c;
    }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" width="787.25" height="599.75" viewBox="0 0 3149 2399">
      <image xlink:href="data:img/png;base64,random symbols..." class="hover" x="2512" y="845" width="310" height="419"/>

       <image xlink:href="data:img/png;base64,random symbols..." x="2413" y="411" width="578" height="543"/>

      </svg>

    </body>
```

Comment: Turn blue? You mean be completely replaced by a blue rectangle the same size as the image?

Comment: is it a line drawing you are trying to change color?  or the box where the image resides?

Comment: It is a line drawing, yes. The image is a transparent outline of several U.S. states. I would like the outline to fill in with blue. Sorry, very new to this.

Comment: certainly achievable with [svg filters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Element/filter) or if js is not an issue, with [canvas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33135691/what-is-the-best-way-to-change-the-color-hue-of-an-image-on-canvas/33163140#comment-54085984)

Answer (score 1):

You're using a bitmap image inside a vector tag (SVG) and this is not wrong but a bad practice.
The way you change colors on an inline SVG is if it's a pure vector graphic (path, polygon, rect...), thus you can use the `fill` property instead of `color` or `background-color`.

```
svg:hover {
    fill: #00599c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[ed1nh0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33222235/2454914) states “this is not wrong but a bad practice”.

And for vector shapes, I would agree.

However, sometimes you may have actual **photo images** that are part of the design *within* the SVG. Maybe there is a good reason for doing it this way, such as if you are using [`<clipPath>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath) to knock out a shape around a photo.

In a situation where changing more than just the fill color, but the *actual image color* is required, you can do it this way:

```html
<!doctype html>

<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Example</title>

<style>
  .hoverable {
    transition: all 1s;
    filter: hue-rotate(90deg);
  }
  .hoverable:hover {
    filter: hue-rotate(180deg);
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
</style>

</head>

<body>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">

  <rect style="fill:#ccc;" width="100%" height="100%" rx="24"/><!-- bg for visualizing bounding box -->

  <!-- under image -->
  <image 
    xml:space="preserve" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
    xlink:href="https://picsum.photos/800/600" 
    x="0%" y="0%" 
    width="800" height="600" 
  />

  <!-- over image -->
  <image 
    class="hoverable" 

    xml:space="preserve" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
    xlink:href="https://picsum.photos/800/600" 
    x="33%" y="25%" 
    width="800" height="600"
  />

</svg>

</body>
</html>
```

The second image, which is layered over the first, has a `.hoverable` class that cycles the hue by `90deg` initially, and then to `180deg` when the cursor is actually triggering the `:hover` pseudo-class.

Styles here are defined in the `<style>` HTML tag in this example (or could be defined in an external .css file), so these are [CSS filters being used on *inline* SVG](https://www.stefanjudis.com/today-i-learned/svgs-filters-can-be-inlined-in-css/).

### if *not* inline...

If you are calling an .svg *file* externally as a CSS `background-image` or something, it will not work. But you can consider having [multiple layered background images](https://css-tricks.com/css-basics-using-multiple-backgrounds/) on the `div` or whatever kind of element it is, with an `rgba()` color overlay of changing `a` (alpha value) for `:hover`, and give the class a [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) if you want.

Alternatively, there are other ways to accomplish a background change using a `transition` on the `opacity`, and such techniques are explained [here](https://coder-coder.com/background-image-opacity/).