# Adjust an image's hue with coldfusion or javascript

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

I have a set of images of cars. They're not the color I need. Playing in paint.net, I realized I can change the hue of the entire image and get pretty close to what I need. Is it at all possible to do this using coldfusion or javascript?

If not, is there any sort of program that I can use to run through a batch of several hundred of them?

Comment: There's a ton of similar questions using the HTML Canvas, but for batch processing this is probably not what you want. Still... http://stackoverflow.com/a/23833834/2813263

Comment: You might check out http://www.imagemagick.org/ and more specifically http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_mods/

Comment: Photoshop can batch edit images in a folder as long as you are editing them the same way every time. It can open the file, perform edits and then save (in the same/different folders with the same/different file names).