# Implement HTML canvas image tinting function

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

First time StackOverflow poster here so please be gentle :)

I am trying to implement image tinting in HTML canvas for a game I'm developing. There were a lot of good suggestions here:

[How do i tint an image with HTML5 Canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688961/how-do-i-tint-an-image-with-html5-canvas)

And I successfully implemented one of those, but the image colours looked too washed out. I was impressed with the results here:

http://www.playmycode.com/blog/2011/06/realtime-image-tinting-on-html5-canvas/

And I tried to play with the code but it's simply not working in the fiddle I'm messing with (can't post a link to JS Fiddle as I don't have enough rep):

```
    function generateRGBKs( img ) {
    var w = img.width;
    var h = img.height;
    var rgbks = [];

    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = w;
    canvas.height = h;

    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage( img, 0, 0 );

    var pixels = ctx.getImageData( 0, 0, w, h ).data;

    // 4 is used to ask for 3 images: red, green, blue and
    // black in that order.
    for ( var rgbI = 0; rgbI < 4; rgbI++ ) {
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width  = w;
        canvas.height = h;

        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.drawImage( img, 0, 0 );
        var to = ctx.getImageData( 0, 0, w, h );
        var toData = to.data;

        for (
                var i = 0, len = pixels.length;
                i < len;
                i += 4
        ) {
            toData[i  ] = (rgbI === 0) ? pixels[i  ] : 0;
            toData[i+1] = (rgbI === 1) ? pixels[i+1] : 0;
            toData[i+2] = (rgbI === 2) ? pixels[i+2] : 0;
            toData[i+3] =                pixels[i+3]    ;
        }

        ctx.putImageData( to, 0, 0 );

        // image is _slightly_ faster then canvas for this, so convert
        var imgComp = new Image();
        imgComp.src = canvas.toDataURL();

        rgbks.push( imgComp );
    }

    return rgbks;
}

function generateTintImage( img, rgbks, red, green, blue ) {
    var buff = document.createElement( "canvas" );
    buff.width  = img.width;
    buff.height = img.height;

    var ctx  = buff.getContext("2d");

    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'copy';
    ctx.drawImage( rgbks[3], 0, 0 );

    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'lighter';
    if ( red > 0 ) {
        ctx.globalAlpha = red   / 255.0;
        ctx.drawImage( rgbks[0], 0, 0 );
    }
    if ( green > 0 ) {
        ctx.globalAlpha = green / 255.0;
        ctx.drawImage( rgbks[1], 0, 0 );
    }
    if ( blue > 0 ) {
        ctx.globalAlpha = blue  / 255.0;
        ctx.drawImage( rgbks[2], 0, 0 );
    }

    return buff;
}

var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    var rgbks = generateRGBKs( img );
    var tintImg = generateTintImage( img, rgbks, 200, 50, 100 );

    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillRect( 0, 0, 100, 100 );

    ctx.drawImage( tintImg, 50, 50 );
}

img.src = "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/413816438701309953/uvZMK_gT_normal.jpeg";
```

I'm sure it's something stupid I've done and nothing wrong with Joe's code - can anyone help me get it working?

Many thanks :)

Comment: Also you should post your Error! I get `Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data. `

Comment: Hi Chad, and thanks for your quick response! I didn't see an error, actually. Also, I'd prefer not to use Base64 encoding, and because all of the images will be kept in the same domain (local folder) as the game code, CORS shouldn't be an issue. I tried using your JS fiddle code in a test project in DreamWeaver but still no luck (using a local image file this time). I'll keep playing with it and let you know how I go shortly...

Comment: if you are loading the files locally file:// then that also breaks CORS, you should set up a simple webserver like http://localhost

Comment: Hmm, CORS is annoying me :( By the way I tried your base64 suggestion and it worked, however it really messes up my code because some of the image files are quite large. I suppose I could store the image data as text in a separate text file and call it. I'll try your localhost solution and see if I can get that working.

Comment: Nope, that didn't work. I tried putting index.html, app.js and image.png on a folder on my web server but it looks like CORS is still a problem: Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data. Not sure why this is now a problem given all files are in the same directory on the same server?

Comment: Oh wait! If I remove the http://www.etc from the img.src and just reference the file name (e.g. just "hair.png") it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're accessing the pixel data the image needs to be on the same domain as the code, or you can try using a base64 src.

```
img.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64,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";
```

You're breaking [CORS](http://caniuse.com/cors) policy

Heres a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/icodeforlove/2A8CJ/)